# mapping an event log to an interval log in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables, an event log and a interval log.

```
import pandas as pd
interval_log = {'interval_id':['AG21234', 'AG21236', 'AS21234'], 
           'start_utc':['2016-01-01 10:30:50', '2016-03-20 09:31:50', '2016-06-20 21:12:30'], 
           'end_utc':['2016-01-02 12:41:00', '2016-03-20 10:12:32', '2016-06-20 23:32:21']}
interval_table = pd.DataFrame(interval_log)

event_log = {'event_id':[12334,13242, 43251, 32123, 43213, 43215, 34221],
         'timestamp':['2016-01-01 10:30:51', '2016-01-01 10:31:51', '2016-01-01 10:35:51',
                      '2016-03-20 09:35:12', '2016-03-20 09:40:23', 
                      '2016-06-20 22:10:30', '2016-06-20 22:21:12'],
        'event_class':['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A'],
        'event_cause':['A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'C4', 'B34', 'D32', 'A12']    }
event_table = pd.DataFrame(event_log)

interval_table.start_utc = pd.to_datetime(interval_table.start_utc)
interval_table.end_utc = pd.to_datetime(interval_table.end_utc)
event_table.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(event_table.timestamp)
```

What I was trying to do was to add the `interval_id` to each entry in the `event_log`
The current working code is to do:

```
result = []
for counter, interval in interval_table.iterrows():
    subset = event_table[(event_table.timestamp > interval.start_utc) & 
                   (event_table.timestamp < interval.end_utc) ]
    subset['interval_id'] = interval.interval_id
    result.append([subset])
```

which works for this trivial case but on the real dataset where the event_log is around 9 million rows and the intervals are around 3 million rows it runs really inefficiently.

what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just learned about `merge_asof` which [from the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) does:

> For each row in the left DataFrame, we select the last row in the
>   right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s
>   key. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.

Both DataFrames must be sorted by their key.

```
pd.merge_asof(event_table, interval_table, left_on='timestamp', right_on='start_utc')
```

Answer (score 1):

use pandas 0.19 [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(
    event_table, interval_table,
    left_on='timestamp', right_on='start_utc'
).drop(['end_utc', 'start_utc'], 1)
```

[image]